# GNU Make: chdir make process itself

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake

Is it possible to use a makefile that directs the make process itself to `chdir`? I want to write a makefile that expects to be executed from the build directory.

Suppose I have a project directory structure that looks like this

```
project/
├── Makefile
├── include
│   └── Foo.h
├── src
│   └── Foo.cpp
└── test
    └── FooTest.cpp
```

and the first thing the make directory does is make a build directory.

```
project/
├── Makefile
├── _build
├── include
│   └── Foo.h
├── src
│   └── Foo.cpp
└── test
    └── FooTest.cpp
```

Is it possible to direct the makefile to `chdir` into `_build` to simplify my rules?

I want to be able to write (for example)

```
foo : Foo.o
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

rather than

```
_build/foo : _build/Foo.o
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I know I can add the build directory to the `VPATH` in order to affect path resolution, but it seems cleaner to just chdir Make itself. Is there a way to do this (preferably without using guile)?

Comment: Try `make -C ...`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I don't think that will work in this case. `-C` changes directory before reading the Makefile rather than "as part of executing the Makefile".

Comment: An  answer here says that you can do it if you have gnu make with Guile support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467969/how-to-change-current-directory-in-make

Comment: @Scooter that is likely to *really* confuse Make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple Makefile that forwards everything:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
.PHONY: ${MAKECMDGOALS}
$(filter-out all,${MAKECMDGOALS}) all: .forward-all ; @:
.forward-all:
        ${MAKE} -C build ${MAKECMDGOALS}
# Never try to remake this makefile.
${MAKEFILE_LIST}: ;
.SUFFIXES:
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Make is not capable of doing this, but NetBSD's `bmake` can do exactly this.

Suppose we have a project with the following structure:

```
.
├── foo.c
├── makefile
└── obj/
```

`foo.c` is a simple C program that depends only on the standard library.

```
/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "hi there");
}
```

The `makefile` uses the common subset of GNU Make and `bmake`. In general, sticking to the common subset is tedious and not worth doing, this is just for the sake of example.

```
default: foo

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

foo : foo.o
    $(CC) -o $@ foo.o
```

Running `bmake` produces the following output

```
$ bmake
cc -c -o foo.o /tmp/make-example/foo.c
cc -o foo foo.o
```

and produces the following directory structure

```
.
├── foo.c
├── makefile
└── obj/
    ├── foo
    └── foo.o
```

It's clear from inspecting the output that `bmake` almost immediately `chdir`ed into the `obj` directory. Paths to outputs in the `obj` directory are relative and paths inside the source directory are absolute.