# How to check whether GNU Make supports Guile

Tags: command-line-arguments, gnu-make, guile

How to check **from the command line** whether GNU Make is built with support of Guile?

Inside Makefile it can be determined via analyzing `.FEATURES` variable (see [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Guile-Function.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is a quasi makefile in stdin.

So, `.FEATURES` variable can be printed in the following way:

```
echo '$(info $(.FEATURES))' | make -f -
```

The following command outputs **`guile`** string if it is supported or nothing in otherwise:

```
echo '$(info $(filter guile,$(.FEATURES)))' | make -f -  2>/dev/null
```

A variation using `grep`:

```
echo '$(info $(.FEATURES))' | make -f - 2>/dev/null | grep -wo guile
```

#### The solution

As @bobbogo mentioned, we can avoid the pipe at all, using [`--eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) option:

```
make --eval '$(info $(filter guile,$(.FEATURES)))' 2>/dev/null
```

This command will print 'guile' or nothing.

Answer (score 3):

As @ruvim points out, the manual says

> You can determine whether GNU Guile support is available by checking the `.FEATURES` variable for the word *guile*.

```
$(if $(filter guile,${.FEATURES}) \
  ,$(info Guile suppoerted, yay!) \
  ,$(error Guile not supported - update your make))
```

Comment: I just needed a shortest **command line one-liner**.
Regarding syntax — `$(...)` variant is the right syntax too (see [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html)).

Comment: @ruvim Ah, sorry, I read your shell lines as _make_ recipes! Blimey, I've gotta get out more. Shortest test is probably to use `--eval` and save a pipe?

Comment: yes, thank you! I have added the variant with `--eval` as the best solutin.