# vpath not picking up newly built objects

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, vpath, automatic-variable

I have this Makefile (and GNU Make):

```
vpath %.o .objs

OBJDIR=.objs

all: symbol_tests.so

symbol_tests.so: symbol_tests.o symbol.o   # simulate linking
    @echo Linking target: $@, prerequisites: $^

%.o: %.c | $(OBJDIR)/
    gcc -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/:
    -mkdir $@
```

but building (without any subdir or objects existing) give me this:

```
mkdir .objs/
gcc -o .objs/symbol_tests.o -c symbol_tests.c
gcc -o .objs/symbol.o -c symbol.c
Linking target: symbol_tests.so, prerequisites: symbol_tests.o symbol.o
```

It is obvious that since neither `symbol.o` nor `symbol_test.o` exists they need to be built.
And they are correctly placed in the subdir `./objs`.

But when "linking" the `vpath` does not pick up the newly created `.o`-files in the `.objs` subdir.

Isn't this strange? Running `make` again gives:

```
Linking target: symbol_tests.so, prerequisites: .objs/symbol_tests.o .objs/symbol.o
```

To me that looks like that in order to trigger the search for the `.o` in the subdir they have to exist when `make` is invoked. That kind of defeats the purpose of `vpath`, doesn't it?

Or is there something wrong with my `Makefile` or understanding of `vpath`?

NOTE: having $(OBJDIR) in the vpath directive does not work. Why?

Comment: As mentioned by Greg, you can't use VPATH to locate object files.  You might consider reading this: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like this will work for GNU Make nor any other Make I've tried.

I think `vpath` and `$(VPATH)` [and for BSD Make `.PATH:`] are only really effective for original sources (i.e. files that exist before Make is invoked, not for any intermediate targets.

In particular see the following caveat from the GNU Autoconf manual:

> Using $< in explicit rules is not portable.  The prerequisite file must be named explicitly in the rule.  If you want to find the prerequisite via a VPATH search, you have to code the whole thing manually.

See more caveats in the Gnu Autoconf manual section [12.14 VPATH and Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/autoconf.html#VPATH-and-Make).

You could of course fool it by doing your final link step in a recursive call to `make`, but that seems wasteful, especially if you do it for lots of targets.

BSD Make manages creation of object directories by automatically changing the current working directory to the object directory and then explicitly finding sources via the `${.CURDIR}` variable -- the location where `make` was first invoked.

GNU Make unfortunately only sets its `$(CURDIR)` *after* it processes `-C` options.  It seems the preferred GNU Make way of doing things (especially in conjunction with the other GNU Autotools) is to use a separate build directory for the Make process.  I.e. create a separate empty build directory and start by running the `configure` script in there, with a relative path to the build directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
```

This creates all the necessary `Makefiles` in the build directory and you can then just run the Make in the build directory as well:

```
gmake
```

That is of course the safest way to ensure no targets (intermediate or otherwise) ever get created in the source directories.

You could also avoid `vpath` and directly add the object directory to each object target name, as in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469528/816536

Comment: I was coming from having `$(OBJDIR)` in front of each prerequsite and felt that was a bit cluttered, but at least it is explicit. I'll consider moving into the `OBJDIR` instead, but probably will just forget about having a separate `OBJDIR`, I'm not doing multi-arch compilation in this project anyway. Or use some `patsubst` magic.